When are enforcer drones summoned?
Shooting down tax drones eventually summons a difficult enforcer/police drone with seeking rockets.  These bad boys are generally a huge pain to deal with.  They tend to blow up all the cash as well.
However, I've noticed that shooting down tax drones only periodically avoids sounding the alarm, but I haven't been able to nail down how it works exactly with testing.
Is it based on how many drones are shot down each wave?  Over time?  How often can I safely shoot down tax drones while avoiding the enforcers?

